# Where is the 'add platform' button in facebook's app dashboard?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I don't seem to find the 'add platform' button anywhere on the basic settings page for my newly created app to configure the platform. Please help me find it. I'm attaching the screenshot as well. Probably just me![image]

Comment: It should be right above the last box with the delete/dicard/save changes buttons. Maybe try another browser? (It seems the whole thing is still quite buggy since they launched it.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks alot man! It works in firefox but not in chrome!